# How to debug an app installation on iPhone (over usb) with iTunes

Tags: ios, cordova, itunes, phonegap

I want to debug the app install on itunes. I have the problem with a phonegap app. I can't install it on the phone. It breaks after 80%. No message on iTunes or the phone. The same app is running on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try https://github.com/sarriaroman/FabricPlugin

This will show you the report of crash, line of code & reason for crash like SIGABRT etc